# Mixing MVC and MVVM with Zk framework

Tags: model-view-controller, mvvm, zk

i am working with a team on a project using ZK framework , the thing is I am comfortable working with MVC and on the other side the whole team is working with MVVM .

i was wondering if it's ok to mix both architectures, that mean some pages with MVC and some with MVVM. Is that a bad idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can mix the 2 technologies.

**I do not support it**, unless the different pages are complete on their own like an `about.zul`.
You just have to take care if your pages will not affect the other team members their pages.

**What do I mean with that :** If your collegue's triggering an `global-command` what is needed to reach your page, you are stuck with the `EventQueue` cause `global-command` is MVVM, so someone has to bend, maybe the other team members has to use `EventQueue` just for you or you have to switch to MVVM.

**Summary :** If it's a whole new project, just go with the team.
You will enjoy the learning of MVVM and see how easy it actually is.
You will also not getting future problems when the teams pages reaches your pages.

MVVM isn't that hard and if you have MVC and ZK in your fingers you switch easily to MVVM.

Comment: thank you for your answer , in term if Functionalities ? is it the same in MVVM? ..for example  depending on what i have read so far using MVVM i cant controle the view programmatically .

Comment: You can still wire components and add components to the view. see here :http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer's_Reference/MVVM/Syntax/ViewModel/Parameters/@ContextParam how you can get your component from a view and you can add whatever you want.

Comment: is that a Good practice ? to wire components in a MVVM project ?

Comment: no, real wiring like MVC not, but you can still do. With the @ContextParam is now the way how you should use it. (and if your component doesn't refresh do an invalidate of your component)